# Yum regular expression or wildcard search?

Tags: regular-expression, yum

Fedora [documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/4/html-single/Software_Management_Guide/) says:

> 5.2. Advanced Searches
>
> If you do not know the name of the package, use the search or provides options. Alternatively, use wild cards or
>   regular expressions with any yum search option to broaden the search
>   critieria.

Well, at first I thought that this is simply wrong or outdated, since no known syntax of regular expressions would work with `yum search`, but then I found [this](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netos/article.php/3665371/Cheatsheet-Master-Linux-Package-Management.htm): `yum search [cl-*]` for example. But it does something otherworldly. It finds things which have neither "c" nor "l" letters in the name or description. (What I wanted is to find all packages, whose names would be matched by `cl-.*` regexp.

I also found few people suggesting to pipe yum results to `grep`, which, of course, solves the problem. But, just on principle, I want to find out what did the thing in the square brackets do. What if `yum` actually can search by regexp?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### searching with YUM

You generally don't use any regular expressions (globs) when searching with `yum search` since the command `search` is already looking for sub-strings within the package names and their summaries. How do I know this? There's a message that tells you this when you use `yum search`.

> Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.

**NOTE:** The string `[cl-*]` is technically a glob in the Bash shell.

So you generally look for fragments of strings that you want with `search`. The regular expressions come into play when you're looking for particular packages. These are the YUM commands like `list` and `install`.

**For example:**

```
$ yum list cl-* | expand
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.dmacc.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.dmacc.net
Available Packages
cl-asdf.noarch                  20101028-5.fc19                 fedora          
cl-clx.noarch                   0.7.4-4.3                       home_zhonghuaren
cl-ppcre.noarch                 2.0.3-3.3                       home_zhonghuaren
```

The only caveat you have to be careful with regexes/globs, is if there are files within your shell that are named such that they too would match`cl-*`. In those cases your shell will expand the regex/glob prior to it being presented to YUM.

So instead of running `yum list cl-*` you'll be running the command `yum list cl-file`, if there's a file matching the regex/glob `cl-*`.

**For example:**

```
$ ls cl-file
cl-file

$ yum list cl-*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

You can guard against this happening by escaping the wildcard like so:

```
$ yum list cl-\* | expand
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.dmacc.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.dmacc.net
Available Packages
cl-asdf.noarch                  20101028-5.fc19                 fedora          
cl-clx.noarch                   0.7.4-4.3                       home_zhonghuaren
cl-ppcre.noarch                 2.0.3-3.3                       home_zhonghuaren
```

#### So what about the brackets

I suspect you have files in your local directory that are getting matched when you used `[cl-*]` as an argument to `yum search`. These files after being matched by the shell, were passed to the `yum search` command where matches where then found.

**For example:**

```
$ ls cl-file
cl-file

$ yum search cl-*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.dmacc.net
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.nexcess.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.dmacc.net
======================================================================= N/S matched: cl-file =======================================================================
opencl-filesystem.noarch : OpenCL filesystem layout

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

**NOTE:** The match above was matched against my file's name, `cl-file`, and not the `cl-*` as I had intended.

Comment: Oooh, I see now. Well, that explains it. One nitpicking remark though `cl-*` isn't a regular expression, it's a `glob` or whatever it's called. It's a regular language (in Chomskian terms), but we usually say that something is a regular expression if it defines a grammar for regular language (by using at least three basic operations: concatenation, alteration and Kleene star).

Comment: @wvxvw - that's correct. You started with the terminology regex and I just leaned into it 8-).

Answer (score 6):

Definitely different yum version, using RHEL 6.5 here with yum 3.2.29
**Beware:**
You should quote the * to not match anything in the current directory via shell globbing ... For more details on that and a practical example, see the later answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155157/83329

Anyways, just checked again, the only way to actually search effectively with yum search is by `yum search all | grep foo` as `yum search foo` gives pretty fuzzy results. But `yum list "foo-*"` works just as expected, and only result in your case would probably be the package cl-asdf.noarch .

Quickly glancing over related yum bugreports yum search seems to also have other drawbacks: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/580336/comments/2

Answer (score 1):

Sorry cannot comment yet so have to use an answer.

Did you try `yum search cl-*` or `yum list 'cl-*'` ?
At least for `yum whatprovides */foo` it works for searching filenames, although that's a bit of a special case. Otherwise I also often use
`yum list all | grep -i foo` but beware of the multiline output of yum, grep might only show the first line, so maybe use `yum list all | grep -iA1 foo`

There are also some useful examples in the man page below "List Options". Additional documentation is also available directly upstream at http://yum.baseurl.org/ e.g. http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands or maybe directly via python: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCodeSnippet/YumSearch

Comment: Did I try `yum search cl-*`? - yes I did. This finds nothing (maybe different yum version? I'm still using FC18).

Comment: Well, from reading on the intented use case for `yum  search`, combining it with regular expressions/wildcards is double-redundant. `yum search` already does a fuzzy search, so using wildcards is pretty useless. If you want to constrain your search, use `yum list expression` or `yum list all | grep expression`. Otherwise I suggest you open an enhancement request against yum - good luck with that :p