# Can't find using yum search, but can see it in yum list

Tags: yum, repository

I got a problem using yum repository in RHEL 6.3.
First, I have created yum repository use rpmforge repository. I can do `yum list` also. Here the last line of yum list result.

```
zssh.x86_64                                    1.5-0.c.2.el6.rf                     rpmforge 
zsync.x86_64                                   0.6.2-1.el6.rf                       rpmforge 
zvbi.x86_64                                    0.2.33-2.el6.rf                      rpmforge 
zvbi-devel.x86_64                              0.2.33-2.el6.rf                      rpmforge 
zziplib.x86_64                                 0.13.45-1.el6.rf                     rpmforge 
zziplib-devel.x86_64                           0.13.45-1.el6.rf                     rpmforge
```

But, If I do yum search for `zzip*`, the result going to be like this

```
[root@noi Downloads]# yum search zzip*
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Warning: No matches found for: zzip*
No Matches found
```

It will be different again when I just installed that,

```
[root@noi Downloads]# yum install zzip*
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zziplib.x86_64 0:0.13.45-1.el6.rf will be installed
---> Package zziplib-devel.x86_64 0:0.13.45-1.el6.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: SDL-devel for package: zziplib-devel-0.13.45-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel for package: zziplib-devel-0.13.45-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zziplib-devel-0.13.45-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: zlib-devel
Error: Package: zziplib-devel-0.13.45-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: SDL-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Anyone knows how it can be happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to replace [nice answer provided by slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155105/yum-regular-expression-or-wildcard-search?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

> You generally don't use any regular expressions (globs) when searching with yum search since the command search is already looking for sub-strings within the package names and their summaries. How do I know this? There's a message that tells you this when you use yum search.
>   **Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.**

Try searching without regular expression `yum search zzip`

Answer (score 0):

If you use yum search you don't have to use asterisk(*) character. Yum search searches for the whole text you entered. Try using "yum search zzip".